# Retrieve value for a key from DynamicFrame class?

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

For Python DynamicFrame, how to retrieve only column value? [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html)

```py
dynamicFrame.show() # getting key and value, for eg: {"key1", "value1"}
```

But I have to retrieve the only value for a particular key (say `"key1"`).

Comment: anyone can? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The show display the column's values. If you want a specific "key" (I guess you mean a specific value for a column) you can simply do:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dynamicFrame.toDF().filter(F.col("mycol") == 'mykey').show()
```